# How to parse json response and add functions like error,complete to it using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, error-handling

I am working on making a mini app using Json parsing . Output I am getting by hitting url   http://localhost:3000/cities.json is as below

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bangalore"
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Chandigarh"
    },
    {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Chennai"
    },
    {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Hyderabad"
    },
]
```

I have parsed this using function

```
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/cities.json?&callback=?", function(data) {
                //something something
 }
```

Now I want to add .error function to it so in case there is some issue with response or say server doesnt respond i may get to know about it say by putting an alert like

```
.error(function(){alert("error");})
```

I tried it in following way

```
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/cities.json?&callback=?", function(data) {
                //something something
         }).error(function(){
            alert("error");
         })
```

I tried it using this way as well

```
     var cities = $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/cities.json");
                   cities.error("hi");
```

But none of them is working. To check for error i stop my local server and it doesnt give me any alert for that . Please guide me which way should i proceed ?

------**EDIT**--------

Also tried using

```
 var jqxhr = $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/cities.json?callback=?", function() {
          alert("success");
        })
        .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
        .error(function() { alert("error"); })
        .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

in case my localhost:3000 server is running it give me alert success and second success but in case i stop it no error call, also making url just **http://localhost:3000/cities.json**
always tend to give error irrespective of server running or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me finally

```
           $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/cities.json?&callback=?",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function(data, status, xmlstatus) {
                call_to_function(data);
            },
            error: function(x, t, m) {
                if (t === "timeout") {
                    $('#spinner').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#spinner').hide();
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ajaxSetup`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  error:function(XMLHttpRequest) {   
    //error
    console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
}});
```

and your `getJSON` goes as usual

```
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/cities.json?&callback=?", function(data) {
                //something something
 });
```

Comment: is it this way ??    $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/cities.json?&callback=?", function(data) {
                       alert("hi");         
                     }
                $.ajaxSetup({
                  "error":function(XMLHttpRequest) {   
                   alert("hello");
                }});

Comment: first define the `ajaxSetup` like in the answer and then define your `$.getJSON` the order matters

Comment: are there any errors in the `firebug` console? have you included the `jquery`? have you wrapped the code inside `$(document).ready(function(){//your code});`? are you specifying the correct path?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BRTB3/ ...and ...http://jsfiddle.net/WNF7W/   here are  the code i wrote and it shows no error in 'firebug (firefox)'...... when server is running it alerts hi and when its stopped no hello. Code is  in '$(document).ready(function(){})'  ... also changing **cities** to **citiies** or something else aso gives no error

Comment: have you checked the path to the file, everything seems to be fine, only thing left is `cross-domain` issue, can you see the ajax call made in the `firebug>Net>XHR` tab?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4204/discussion-between-sahil-grover-and-3nigma)

Comment: it gives just on alert that too of hi

Comment: @SahilGrover do you have a query? i was not around

Answer (score 0):

Function that you use now is just a shorthand for for [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) looking like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

If you change your code to $.ajax, you can use `error` the same way you use `success`. Or alternatively you can use [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to set default error handler for your ajax calls.

Comment: 1.   url: "http://localhost:3000/cities"  2.   url: "http://localhost:3000/cities.json" 3.    url: "http://localhost:3000/cities.json?callback=?" none of them gives           success: function(){alert("hello");}

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the json data, you should create a parameter called error.  Set it to false by default, and true if an error arises.  Then check the error value when you getJSON.

Otherwise, I might recommend using

```
.get("", {}, function(json){
   try{
     var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
   }catch(err){ console.log(err); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You last method should work but you have to specify a function for error:-

```
var cities = $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/cities.json");
cities.error(function(){
    alert('error');
});
```

OR you can use:-

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback,
  error: callback
});
```